# Problema con el compilador en Dev C++

Tags: compilador

Cuando ejecuto Dev-C++ para hacer mis programas siempre aparece esta ventana con un error del compilador al inicio. ¿A qué se debe y cómo puedo solucionar el error?.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has intentado darle clic al botón _Yes_?

Comment: Al dar clic en ese botón funciona y puedo trabajar, pero deseo quitar ese error, es un poco molesto, en mi anterior PC no aparecía ese error.

Comment: Luego de dar clic en yes, guarda de nuevo el _compiler set_, de esta manera asumo que la siguiente vez ya no debiera preguntar.